# Showing DLL-symbols of an attached process

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dll, watcom

About 15 years ago I reverse-engineered some Windows-programs with the Watcom Debugger. One thing that was advantageous with the Watcom Debugger was, that it could show the exported symbols of the loaded DLLs.

When I attach to a running process with Visual Studio 2015 Community Ed. I'm missing this feature. Can anyone tell me how to list the loaded DLLs and their symbols?

Comment: Use the Dumpbin.exe utility with the /exports option to see all exported symbols.  Use the debugger's Debug > Windows > Modules debugger window to see all loaded DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windbg for this.  Download and install the [Windows Debugging Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx), fire up windbg and hit F6 to attach to a running process.  It will immediately show the DLL's loaded, but if you enter the command `lm` you'll get a list of loaded modules, as well as their start and end points in memory.